# Is the backslash n `\n` really Line Feed, but is treated as a Newline?

Tags: ascii, newline, carriage-return, linefeed

For all the years using C, Ruby, Perl, Java, and PHP, or many other languages, I just took `\n` to mean newline.  So turns out it is only "Line Feed" but is treated as "Newline"?

It looks like the following are some facts, some of them from [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline):

1. `\n` is Line Feed, not Newline, but is treated by almost all systems to mean "a new line".
2. In theory, `\r\n` is really what a newline is, because it moves the cursor back to the first position horizontally, and move the cursor down one row.  However, although some systems use this as the Newline (Windows), some systems just treat a single `\n` to mean Newline (Unix, Linux, Mac).
3. There were some systems that actually had a Newline character, such as on IBM mainframe and ZX80, but it never became a character in ASCII, and we almost never use it.
4. So in ASCII, we really still only have Carriage Return `\r` which is `0x0d` (Decimal 13), and Line Feed `\n`, which is 0x0a (Decimal 10).
5. And as far as programming is concerned, outputting the `0x0a` character is meant to be a Newline, although in reality it is only a Line Feed.
6. Theoretically, if we output `0x0a`, one can argue that the next output will continue at the same horizontal position as the previous line, instead of at the left most position, but in practice, it is not. It is always the left most position on most systems.
7. The `\r` is still being used by some program to keep outputting information on the same line and not scroll up. This works although we never know how many "blank spaces" to print out to cover up the old information. It can be done by the ANSI escape sequence `\033[K` to clear from the cursor to the end of line, or more correctly using some curses library that works on that particular platform.

I think two main take away points are

1. We really don't have a newline character, but we take the `\n`, which is Line Feed, to mean Newline, and most system just treat this Line Feed to "mean" Newline.
2. It is really `0x0a`, just to set the record straight. I thought for many years it is `0x0d` but it is not.

Are the above accurate, or any correction or addition?

Comment: At the end of the day, it's just a byte, and how systems interpret it is up to them.  It's not "really" one thing or another.

Comment: well, the reason was one time, I got grilled at an interview (at Google) what is line feed, what is newline, what is carriage return, and what is `\n` and `\r`... it is best to set the record straight

Comment: From what I've always understood, a 'newline' is a visual manifestation most commonly based on CRLF or LF and CR alone. The interpretation of the control characters will vary per OS and other implementations.

Answer (score 3):

Nowadays there are the following line endings ("newlines"):

- `Old MacOS`      0x0D = 13 = CR = `\r` = carriage return
- `Linux`          0x0A = 10 = LF = `\n` = linefeed
- `AS400`          0x85 = EBCDIC NL = NEL
- `Windows`        0x0D 0x0A = CR-LF = `\r\n`

CR, LF stem from the mechanical type writer with a paper holding carriage.
CR caused by a handle on the right end of the carriage caused it the carriage to be released back to the left. LF rolled the carriage two half lines up.

A language like Java took the strategy to read the lines *without* passing the newline character(s). It can deal with any line endings. For the current platform it provides a property holding the actual newline (line separator).

For pattern matching there exists regular expression `\R` (Java `"\\R"`) to match any newline sequence.

Comment: I tried printing out `\n` in Ruby on a Mac, and it gave out a single `0x0a`... I think probably the same if it is C or Java on a Mac. On Windows it probably gives out `0x0d 0x0a` still...

Comment: @nonopolarity In java `\r,\n,\r\n` are fixed `\u000d,\u000a,\u000d\u000a`. In other languages `\n` might be reinterpreted on Windows as `0x0d 0x0a` as you said. Which is a portability measure of C, as many C (Unix) programs predated Windows. Mac OS nowadays is part of the Unix family with its `\n`,

Answer (score 1):

New Line is an abstract name for a text file line terminator.   On Win machines, it is implemented as a 0x0d0a.  On Unix machines it is implemented as a 0x0a.  On old Macs it is implemented as an 0x0d.

Those implementation values are all ASCII characters.  They are inherited from teletypes.
0x0d actually caused the carriage to move so the next character printed is in column 1.  0x0a actually caused the carriage to rotate one line.

I used to see this on a [Model 33 Teletype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teletype_Model_33) :)

Another place terms can get get confusing is the ASCII NUL character.  It's value is 0x00.  You sometimes see it in code as '\0'.   A lot of people refer to it as NULL, which is a pointer value in C/C++ whose value is normally 0.

Comment: because the Mac can go back as far as 1984, when old Mac is mentioned, is it the Mac before 1997, 1998, or more recently like 2007?

Comment: I don't have the date.   There was a point where they basically switched to Unix.   When that happened 0x0d -> 0x0a.

Answer (score 0):

I meant to write this as a comment but I can't.

While reading the [Build Your Own Text Editor](https://viewsourcecode.org/snaptoken/kilo/) tutorial, I came across this in the [Fix Ctrl-M](https://viewsourcecode.org/snaptoken/kilo/02.enteringRawMode.html#fix-ctrl-m) section:

> It turns out that the terminal is helpfully translating any carriage
> returns (13, '\r') inputted by the user into newlines (10, '\n').

Later it talks about output processing:

> It turns out that the terminal does a similar translation on the
> output side. It translates each newline ("\n") we print into a
> carriage return followed by a newline ("\r\n").

If you look at the man for [termios(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html) it says:

> ICRNL  Translate carriage return to newline on input (unless IGNCR is set).

> OPOST  Enable implementation-defined output processing.